experiensing "Protocol vfs has not been enabled as an allowed protocol" error while deploying the Spring boot WS to JBoss EAP 8
I am working on developing a spring boot(3.3.5) web service with log4j2 as my logging library. I generated a spring boot project from spring initializer, excluded the logging from web module to exclude the logback from the spring boot and added the following log4j2 recommended dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

added properties to config how to log
<log.entry.pattern><![CDATA[%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %t | %-5p | %c{1}: %m%n]]></log.entry.pattern>
<log.file.root>/service/logs</log.file.root>
<log.file.name>${log.file.root}/${project.artifactId}/${project.artifactId}.log</log.file.name>
<log.file.pattern>${log.file.root}/${project.artifactId}/${project.artifactId}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</log.file.pattern>

added log4j2-spring.xml as follows in the src/main/resources
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FILE"
            fileName="/service/logs/@project.artifactId@/@project.artifactId@.log"
            filePattern="/service/logs/@project.artifactId@/@project.artifactId@-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern><![CDATA[%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %t | %-5p | %c{1}: %m%n]]></pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

added controller method to just have some basic logging messages
    @GetMapping("/testlogs")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void fetch() {

        LOGGER.debug("Debug log message");
        LOGGER.info("Info log message");
        LOGGER.error("Error log message");
        LOGGER.warn("Warn log message");
        LOGGER.trace("Trace log message");
    }

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks as below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
            <subsystem name="datasources" />
            <subsystem name="ejb3" />
            <subsystem name="infinispan" />
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="jca" />
            <subsystem name="jmx" />
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
            <subsystem name="jsf" />
            <subsystem name="mail" />
            <subsystem name="pojo" />
            <subsystem name="remoting" />
            <subsystem name="resource-adapters" />
            <subsystem name="sar" />
            <subsystem name="security" />
            <subsystem name="transactions" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="weld" />
            <subsystem name="bean-validation" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

my folder structure is as follows

experiencing the following error in Jboss EAP 8
{"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"ProvAccess" => {"host" => {"BCDEVINTRAJB099-primary" => {"ProvAccs1_1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"logtest.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Log4J2 logging from classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Log4J2 logging from classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Log4J2 logging from classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Log4J2 logging from classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
    Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Protocol vfs has not been enabled as an allowed protocol"}}}}}}}}



I'm going to be a bit blunt here. You remove nearly all the benefits of WildFly from your deployment. Why use WildFly at all?

@JamesR.Perkins That's the good point, I think Its mainly servlets part of Jboss that we use but not others, on top of it we decided to use spring boot which brings its own flavors of libraries into the mix and causing problems. Its mainly that. reason. Please let me know if you can able to reproduce this issue on your end?

@JamesR.Perkins On top of that I have more apps that uses lot of more jboss subsystems, but for spring boot app which is one of the tech I use for developing webservices, we exclude most of the subsystems.

Well, it makes sense if you have other deployments on WildFly. I was mostly curious as the benefit of WildFly, or any Jakarta EE server, is having the dependencies included. I unfortunately don't know enough about Spring Boot, but it sounds like you've got it solved :)

The Log4j configuration file has similar capabilities as the Spring XML bean definitions and for these reason it must come from a trusted source (see the threat model). This is why Log4j Core places restrictions on the URLs that can be used to retrieve the configuration file (see log4j2.configurationAllowedProtocols configuration property.
By default, configuration files can only be retrieved from URLs with a file, jar or https schema. In your case the location of your log4j2-spring.xml file is exposed to users using a vfs: schema. Setting the log4j2.configurationAllowedProtocols Log4j configuration property to vfs should solve your problem.
You can also do it by adding a log4j2.component.properties file to the root of your classpath with content:
log4j2.configurationAllowedProtocols = vfs


this fixed the issue, but I couldn't understand how you are saying that the log4j2-spring.xml is exposed to users using a vfs? can I disable it and not use this property or how can I use one of the default way?

I don't know how vfs works in Wildfly, but if you were to allow http for example, the configuration file could be intercepted and modified by an attacker. Probably he wouldn't be able to execute arbitrary code, but he could e.g. eavesdrop on all the logs.

The vfs, Virtual File System, has been used in JBoss AS and WIldFly for a long time. It's effectively like a ZIP file system. It's what WildFly uses as mount points for deployments.
